# Failing to get text from EditText to textview Android

Tags: android, android-view

I have been having problems getting text from EditText to TextView, the EditText is being inflated in a custom Action bar, I know the solution is pretty simple but I cannot figure out a way around it, I am able to do this in other activities but failing to do it in this activity, below is my code:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_customactionbar, null);
ImageButton mstartsearch = (ImageButton) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.msearch1);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
searchbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchbox1);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

searchQuery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.itemName);
searchQuery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

mstartsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      searchQuery.setText(searchbox.getText().toString());
      searchQuery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  }
});
```

When I run this code am getting the error below:

```
 at aubry.chromio.com.letstalksampo.SearchPost$1.onClick(SearchPost.java:154)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18599)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5883)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:688)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: `searchbox = (EditText)mCustomView .findViewById(R.id.searchbox1);` and  `searchQuery = (TextView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);`

Comment: can you tell which is the line no 154.. and try printing a toast to know if the text is extracted from the edittext or not..

Comment: You would be better off using a [FilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html)! Or if you dont like that, just use a textwatcher on your editText

Comment: Prakhar line 154 is searchQuery.setText(searchbox.getText().toString());

Comment: @Skynet can you please explain further?

Comment: @MD I don't get your answer, can you please break it down?

Comment: @MD thanks a lot, its amazing how something so small can ruin a day.

Comment: @Chrome Yee!!!! It's easy.Just used your Mind......

Comment: @Chrome look MD is trying to say that is your (R.id.searchbox1) is in mCustomview than you have to use mCustomView .findViewById(R.id.searchbox1); and also same for that textView.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso its been solved, I was forgetting to  include mCustomView  when initializing searchbox

Comment: @Chrome, all you want is to provide search functionality? Am I right?